# how do you secure mysql without a server root password?

Tags: mysql, password, root, centos6.5

I'm currently trying to install mySQL server on a centos6.5 server.
I do not have a root password because i use a SSH Key Pair to access the server.

During the installation process the prompt says:

> "In order to log into MySQL to secure it, we'll need the current
>   password for the root user. If you've just installed MySQL, and you
>   haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank, so you
>   should just press enter here."

Pressing enter without giving a password then gives this prompt:

> Setting the root password ensures that nobody can log into the MySQL
>   root user without the proper authorization. Set root password? [Y/n]

Is this asking me to create a root password for the server or a separate root password just for mysql? If it wants to set a server root password, is there a way to secure mysql without having a set server root password?

Comment: It's the password for the root user within MySQL.  It has no bearing on the OS's root user:  `the MySQL root user`

Comment: Ok thank you. It would be so much clearer if the prompt said set MySQL root password instead of just root password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Is this asking me to create a root password for the server or a separate root password just for mysql?`

It is asking you to setup a root password for MySQL only. Not a root password for your server OS.

MySQL does not take care about operating system root password. It is only interested about its own root password to protect itself.